# Cannot Type cast using Firebase Admin & Google Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I need to type cast some variables, but for some reason I am finding the types impossible to import via `firebase-admin`.

Here is an over-simplified example.

```js
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'
import { Bucket } from 'where??'

admin.initializeApp()

exports.myFunc = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(async myFile => {
    const bucket = admin.storage().bucket() // this works
    const bucket: Bucket = admin.storage().bucket() // but I want to do this
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I was required to install and import the following package:

`import { Bucket } from @google-cloud/storage`